# Executing a stored procedure in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for some help in getting the following stored proc to work: I get anonymous block completed and not able to see the result. It works perfectly fine in PL/SQL devloper's "tes" window, but I would like to see it work in the ORACLE SQL Developer

---

```
DECLARE  
TYPE OUTPUT_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR  
t_c OUTPUT_CURSOR  
BEGIN  
P_M.E_S.T_S_QUERY( 123,'ABC','20100101','20100131','ALL',:t_c);    
END;
```

Comment: Are you clicking the "View Script Output" in the output tab at the bottom of the page? 
I think by default it shows a grid view - which when executing a PL/SQL block wont populate with anything.

Comment: No luck with View | Script output, the window is still blak. The "anonymous block coompleted" shows up in the statement output window. I also tried the "+" button, it pops up a "Select connection" dialog but does not show the result.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you enable the DBMS Output using **"View->DBMS Output"** and clicking **"+"** button in the resulting window.

Comment: ah yes i forgot about that option aswell

Answer (score 0):

In SQL developer we can see the **Stored Procedure** output by enabling DBMS OUTPUT. You can go to VIEW menu and find this option. (Don't forget to enable DBMS output for the desired connection by pressing **CTRL+N** (the + button))

Hope this makes sense.  :)